# Executing a cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a cursor that calls a function which returns a table. Both the cursor and function are in a package. How can I execute this cursor to see the output?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the cursor is defined (or at least declared) in the package specification, you can run it and loop over the results from an anonymous block:

```
begin
  for r in your_package.your_cursor loop
    -- do something with result row, e.g.
    -- dbms_output.put_line(r.your_column);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

As a simple example:

```
create package your_package as
  cursor your_cursor is
    select dummy from dual;
end;
/
```

```
begin
  for r in your_package.your_cursor loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.dummy);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
X
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UXtV79wf)

That also works with just the cursor declaration in the specification, and the cursor body in the package body ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_KxZ1h7Y)).

If the cursor is only in the package body, and not in the specification, then it won't be visible or accessible outside the package.